# Beispielnummer oder Beispielsnummer?

Tags: noun, compound

Im Netz steht beides (und da steht vieles). Der Kontext (aus dem Redakteuralltag) lautet wie folgt.

Haupttext:

> Wie man leicht anhand des Beispiels 1.2.3.4 sieht, sind Krokodile unten lang und oben lang, aber nur oben grün. Also sind sie länger als grün.

Anmerkung eines Redakteurs:

> Der obige Absatz wurde verbessert. Dabei wurde die richtige Beispiel[s]nummer eingefügt.

Mit Fugen-s oder ohne Fugen-s hier? Warum?

Duden, Wahrig, die Rechtschreibregeln und korrekturen.de fand ich hier nicht hilfreich.  Bastian Sick spricht im Zweibelfisch über Zusammensetzungen, deren erster Bestandteil auf -el endet, aber in allen seinen Beispielen wird "el" als "l" oder "əl" gelesen (Hagelschauer, Hebelgesetz, Kabeltrommel, Kegelklub, Mandelaugen, Nebelhorn, Paddelboot, Pendeluhr, Wendeltreppe), während wir die Aussprache von "Beispiel" mit "...i:l" enden.

Comment: Gute Frage. Ein Beispiel mit Nummer oder die Nummer des Beispiels. Dativ oder Genitiv. Ich weiß es nicht, aber andere bestimmt :-) Paddelboot ist etwas anderes, denke ich. Ein Boot mit Paddeln oder zum paddeln (also Paddelboot) ist da klarer für mein Verständnis, aber ich kann mich irren.

Comment: Als Muttersprachler aus dem Norden sagt mein Bauchgefühl **Beispielnummer**. (Anm.: *Ich bin nicht an dem Kampf gegen das "Fugen-s" beteiligt.*)

Comment: Bootspaddel, Haushaltsreiniger, Essensreste ... deutsch ist einfach nicht durchgängig regelmäßig ... :-)

Comment: Jedenfalls heißt es 'Krokodilstränen' und nicht 'Krokodiltränen', soviel scheint klar.

Comment: IMO gibt es zum Gebrauch des Fugen-s keine Regel. Der Gebrauch wird vermutlich von der Aussprechbarkeit bestimmt; wenn die Zunge stolpern könnte, wird ein 's' als Schmiermittel eingefügt. Mitunter ist auch beides gebräuchlich, siehe z.B. Einkommen(s)steuer.

Answer (score 5):

Das Problem mit dem Fugen-S ist, dass es keine feste Regel gibt. Es gibt zwar einige allgemeine Regeln, aber gleichzeitig wieder viele viele Ausnahmen von diesen. Teilweise sind diese auch noch regional bedingt, z.B.

> Adventkalender (österr.)
>
> Adventskalender (dt.)

oder [Fälle](http://kommunikationsabc.de/2014/04/30/dieses-verdammte-fugen-s/) in denen die "staatliche" Schreibweise von der des "Volkes" abweicht, z.B.

> [Einkommensteuer](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Einkommensteuer)
>
> [Einkommenssteuer](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Einkommenssteuer)

Im [Duden-Newsletter vom 20.04.2001](https://web.archive.org/web/20040623232717/www.duden.de/service/newsletterarchiv/archiv/2001/010420.html) (Link via WaybackMachine) steht

> Ob ein Fugen-s steht oder nicht, hängt fast immer vom ersten Bestandteil des Kompositums, dem so genannten Bestimmungswort, ab. [...] In Zweifelsfällen lohnt es sich deshalb, im Wörterbuch nach Komposita mit dem gleichen Bestimmungswort zu suchen, [...]. Oft werden Sie feststellen, dass beides möglich ist, die Schreibung mit und ohne Fugen-s!

Macht man sich im Falle des Bestimmungsworts Beispiel auf die (Duden-)Suche finden wir folgende Worte:

> Beispiel
>
> Beispielhaftigkeit
>
> Beispielsammlung
>
> Beispielsatz
>
> Beispielsfall
>
> Beispielswirkung

was uns nicht viel weiterhilft, außer langsam zur Erkenntnis zu kommen, dass beides(!) verwendet wird.

Dazu muss man sagen, dass das Fugen-S seit einiger Zeit auf dem Vormarsch ist. Wörter die früher normalerweise ohne Fugen-S geschrieben wurden werden mittlerweile mit diesem geschrieben, was auf einen Sprachwandel hindeutet. Dies führt dazu, dass viele Zweifelsfälle entstehen, wobei

> Ein  sprachlicher  Zweifelsfall  ist  [...]  “einesprachliche Einheit (Wort/Wortform/Satz), bei der kompetente Sprecherim  Blick  auf  (mindestens)  zwei  Varianten  (a,  b  ...)  in  Zweifel  geraten können,  welche  der  beiden  Formen  (standardsprachlich)  korrekt  ist”

Das [Paper](https://www.germanistik.uni-mainz.de/files/2015/03/Nubling_Szczepaniak_2011_Fugen_Zweifelsfalle-2.pdf) mit diesem Zitat ist allgemein lesenswert, denn es zeigt uns auch, wo welche Variante benutzt wird. So tritt das Fugen-S häufiger in Foren oder Blogs auf, als etwa in Büchern (Seite 60).

Deine Google-Suche zeigte bereits, dass man beide Begriffe finden kann. Schaut man sich die Suchergebnisse allerdings genauer an sieht man auch hier, dass die Variante ohne Fugen-S in Büchern und Anleitungen verwendet wird und die mit Fugen-S eher in (neueren) Blogs und Foren auftaucht.

Für das Fugen-S spricht allerdings evtl, dass man "Beispielnummer 123" auch als "Beispiel Nummer 123" verstehen könnte.

> Dank ihrer phonologischen Salienz markiert die Fuge,häufig als extrasilbisches Element, den rechten Rand des letzten phonologischen Wortes im Erstglied und fördert hierdurch die hörerseitige Segmentierung der morphologischen Struktur der Komposita (Seite 68)

In dem Sinne: Möglich wäre (wahrscheinlich) beides, allerdings würde ich, da

> a) ähnliche Worte ohne Fugen-S auskommen
>
> b) und vor allem im redaktionellen Umfeld meist auf das Fugen-S verzichtet wird

ebenfalls darauf verzichten und die Beispielnummer nehmen.

Answer (score 1):

Nach meinem Sprachgefühl gibt es beides, allerdings mit unterschiedlicher Bedeutung.

#### Beispielsnummer

*Beispiel**s**nummer* mit Fugen-S ist meines Erachtens eine Zusammenrückung der ursprünglich selbständigen Wörter *Beispiel* und *Nummer*, wobei das [Vorderwort im Genitiv](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fugenlaut#Bildung_zusammengesetzter_W%C3%B6rter) steht (des Beispiels Nummer). Ihr Kontextsatz

> Wie man leicht anhand des Beispiels 1.2.3.4 sieht […]

besagt ja gerade, dass 1.2.3.4 des Beispiels Nummer ist, also die *Beispiel**s**nummer*.

#### Beispielnummer

*Beispielnummer* ohne Fugen-S ist für mich eine Nummer, die selber als Beispiel dient – ganz analog zu Zusammensetzungen wie *Beispielsatz* oder *Beispielwort*, wo ein Satz oder ein Wort Gegenstand eines Beispiels ist:

> - Wir analysieren den *Beispielsatz* „Ich bin müde.“
> - Lagerregal ist ein *Beispielwort* für ein Palindrom.
> - Handynummern, wie die *Beispielnummer* 0171 234 567 89, …

Comment: @Just_A_Man, ich zitiere *DUDEN 4. Die Grammatik. 9. Auflage, Randnummer 1089*: „Fugenelemente haben sich historisch größtenteils aus Flexionsendungen entwickelt [...], und zwar aus denen vorangestellter Genitivattribute, die mit ihrem Bezugswort im Laufe der Sprachgeschichte zu einem Wort zusammengerückt sind (*des Tages Licht > Tageslicht*).“